# new symfony flex what is parameters.yml solution

Tags: symfony-flex

I start move to Symfony Flex structure, but cannot find more informations about parameters.yml and parameters.yml.dist - its removed ? how now create bundles with on install ask abount configuration details like we have in older versions ?

Answer (score 1):

Bundles now have their own configuration files which will be installed to the config folder by flex.
To my knowledge parameters.yml is not used anymore, instead you're encouraged to use environment variables and the .env file in root.